# php mail() doesn't send email

Tags: php, email

I have configured a php page for sending email once a submit button is pressed,

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    // impostazioni per invio email
    $to = $query2['email']; // email destinatario
    $from = "info@xxxx.it". "\r\n" ; // email mittente
    $subject = $oggetto;
    $message = $_POST['testoconferma'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)
```

I cannot figure out why once pressed it doesn't send the email.
Did I forgot something?

Comment: are you working on local server (xampp, wampp etc) or online server

Comment: I am working online, I've tried with another script found on the internet and I worked...

Comment: Your web server have to install `sendmail` command. You can use `ssmtp` or `postfix`